# How to format a string will trailing zeroes (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a text return value of "3.5".
I would need to format it to show "3.50"..

How do I do this?

It is all in strings as the value is extracted from a textfield

thanks

Comment: Will it always be a zero?

Comment: %f.2  like this formate .

Answer (score 2):

You can just print with a String initializer

```
if let value = Double(stringValue) {
    print("I want two precision point for \(value) to be \(String(format: "%.2f", value))")
}
```

It will output to `I want two precision point for 3.5 to be 3.50\n`

Comment: The OP has a string, not a number.

Comment: Thanks mate.. I guess I need to know what ""%.2f"" reference too. Where can I get this reference.. let me guess, Apple Developer ref?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: There you go. It's more like a programming thing though, than an iOS/Swift thing, the 2 stands for positional specifier, so if you want to print out 3.500, just replace .2f to .3f. the 'f' there just means that it's a floating point number.

Comment: Do accept the answer if this is indeed what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  'NSNumberFormatter' to format the amount values as given below:

```
let currencyFormatter: NSNumberFormatter = {
    let currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    currencyFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en")
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
    return currencyFormatter
}()

func formattedStringForAmount(amount: String) -> String {
    return currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(Double(amount)!)!
}
```